# CodeIgniter Join Fields Help?

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-design, codeigniter-datamapper

I need help constructing a CodeIgniter Datamapper ORM query that includes join fields.
I have a table of *Merchants* and a table of *Vendors*. 
They have a many-to-one relationship, that is, many *Merchants* are part of a single *Vendor*.

Thus, my datebase tables, following the Datamapper ORM convention are:

**merchants**

**vendors**

**merchants_vendors**

Furthermore, in the **merchants_vendors** table, I have join fields 'role' and 'admin'.
Obviously, this data must be placed in the join table, if it were placed in the *Merchants* table, I  wouldn't be able to define roles and administrators per *Vendor*.

Lastly, *Merchants* are related to *Users* by a one-to-one relationship.
Think of *Merchants* as just an extension of *Users*.

I'm attempting to create a PHP array from the data that follows this data structure, but I can't seem to get the role and admin fields populating properly. I removed redundant columns for your simplicity:

```
[vendor] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Vendor1
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 277
                            [username] => merchant1
                            [firstname] => Merchant1
                            [merchant] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [user_id] => 277
                                    [role] => Sales
                                    [admin] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 282
                            [username] => merchant2
                            [firstname] => Merchant2
                            [merchant] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [user_id] => 282
                                    [role] => Software
                                    [admin] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Here's the code I'm using - Assuming we know the Vendor ID:

```
$v = new Vendor($id);
if($v->exists())
{
    $d['vendor'] = $v->to_array();
    $m = new Merchant();
    $m->where_related_vendor('id', $v->id)->get();
    if($m->exists())
    {
        foreach($m as $mK => $mV)
        {  
            $u = new User();
            $u->where_related_merchant('id', $mV->id)->get();
            $d['vendor']['users'][$mK] = $u->to_array();
            $d['vendor']['users'][$mK]['merchant'] = $mV->to_array();
        }
    }
}
$this->load->view('myview', $d);
```

This gets me as far as the above PHP data structure *without the role and admin.*
I am well aware of the `include_join_fields()` function - but I cannot seem to get it working. Specifically, I tried `$m->vendor->include_join_fields();` Then tried to access the role/admin fields by `$mV->vendor->join_role` and `$mV->vendor->join_admin` - but that doesn't work.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use include_join_fields() on the $mV object inside the forloop:

```
$v = new Vendor($id);
if($v->exists())
{
    $d['vendor'] = $v->to_array();
    $m = new Merchant();
    $m->where_related_vendor('id', $v->id)->get();
    if($m->exists())
    {
        foreach($m as $mK => $mV)
        {  
            $u = new User();
            $u->where_related_merchant('id', $mV->id)->get();

            $mV->vendor->where('id', $v->id)->include_join_fields();

            $d['vendor']['users'][$mK] = $u->to_array();
            $d['vendor']['users'][$mK]['merchant'] = $mV->to_array();
            $d['vendor']['users'][$mK]['merchant']['role'] = $mV->vendor->join_role;
            $d['vendor']['users'][$mK]['merchant']['admin'] = $mV->vendor->join_admin;
        }
    }
}
$this->load->view('myview', $d);
```

Ongoing discussion [in the CodeIgniter forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/205011/).

I will post more information as it arrives.

Answer (score 0):

include_join_fields() doesn't execute anything, it just sets a flag that you want these fields included.

Both examples above miss the get() that actually executes the query...